# Numpy broadcasting in z direction

Tags: python, numpy, broadcasting

In a machine learning context, I need to do a per-element multiplication. To do this efficiently, I need to broadcast elements of a 3D tensor in a particular way such that each 2x2 matrix is repeated n times, as shown by the following example with n=2:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.linspace(1,12,12)
a = a.reshape(3,2,2)

# what to put here?
<some statements>

print a

# result:
[[[  1.   2.]
  [  3.   4.]]

 [[  1.   2.]
  [  3.   4.]]

 [[  5.   6.]
  [  7.   8.]]

 [[  5.   6.]
  [  7.   8.]]

 [[  9.  10.]
  [ 11.  12.]]

 [[  9.  10.]
  [ 11.  12.]]]
```

What statement(s) would do the job?

Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @Divakar! If you want to put it as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one with [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) to replicate along the first axis after you have `a` as a `3D` array -

```
N = 2 # replication number
out = np.repeat(a,N,axis=0)
```

Alternatively, for a `4D` read-only output, we can create a view with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) and that would be very efficient, as we won't be hogging up any extra memory, like so -

```
m,n,r = a.shape
out = np.broadcast_to(a[:,None],(m,N,n,r))

# Confirm it's a view
In [32]: np.shares_memory(a, out)
Out[32]: True
```

Comment: Is it also possible to use `np.tile`? I was trying like this `np.tile(a, (2, 1, 1))` but the repetition is not consecutive :( although the resulting shape matches perfectly

Comment: @kmario23 Yup! With few reshapes -
 `np.tile(a.reshape(-1,4),2).reshape(-1,2,2)`. Reshapes are always handy :)